# How to link dynamical library in Qt

Tags: linux, qt

i'm developing app using QT Creator and external library - librachive. But i cant link it with my project. I have a library file libarchive.so.13.1.2 in my project folder, and  this string in my .pro file:

```
LIBS += -L$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_ -llibarchive.so.13.1.2
```

And i have an error :-1: error: cannot find -llibarchive.so.13.1.2. I'd tried different filenames and symlinks. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: try -larchive instead

Comment: @Shf already tried... still nothing new

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
LIBS += -L$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_ -larchive.so.13.1.2
```

Comment: the same result... i've tried -larchive.so.13.1.2, -larchive.so, -larchive.so.13, -larchive ...

Comment: Does your libarchive.so.13.1.2 exists in the same directory as your .pro file? Do you run qmake after changes in your pro file?